# C++ Function passed as Template Argument vs Parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates

In C++, there are two ways of passing a function into another function that seem equivalent.

```
#include <iostream>

int add1(int i){ return i+1; }
int add2(int i){ return i+2; }

template <int (*T)(int) >
void doTemplate(int i){
    std::cout << "Do Template: " << T(i) << "\n";
}

void doParam(int i, int (*f)(int)){
    std::cout << "Do Param: " << f(i) << "\n";
}

int main(){
    doTemplate<add1>(0);
    doTemplate<add2>(0);

    doParam(0, add1);
    doParam(0, add2);
}
```

doTemplate accepts a function as a template argument, whereas doParam accepts it as a function pointer, and they both seem to give the same result.

What are the trade-offs between using each method?

Comment: Try `doParam(0, some_condition ? add1 : add2)` to see the difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The template-based version allows the compiler to inline the call, because the address of the function is known at compile-time. Obviously, the disadvantage is that the address of the function *has* to be known at compile-time (since you are using it as a template argument), and sometimes this may not be possible.

That brings us to the second case, where the function pointer may be determined only at run-time, thus making it impossible for the compiler to perform the inlining, but giving you the flexibility of determining at run-time the function to be called:

```
bool runtimeBooleanExpr = /* ... */;
doParam(0, runtimeBooleanExpr ? add1 : add2);
```

Notice, however, that there is a third way:

```
template<typename F>
void doParam(int i, F f){
    std::cout << "Do Param: " << f(i) << "\n";
}
```

Which gives you more flexibility and still has the advantage of knowing at compile-time what function is going to be called:

```
doParam(0, add1);
doParam(0, add2);
```

And it also allows passing *any callable object* instead of a function pointer:

```
doParam(0, my_functor());

int fortyTwo = 42;
doParam(0, [=] (int i) { return i + fortyTwo; /* or whatever... */ }
```

For completeness, there is also a *fourth* way, using `std::function`:

```
void doParam(int x, std::function<int(int)> f);
```

Which has the same level of generality (in that you can pass any callable object), but also allows you to determine the callable object at run-time - most likely with a performance penalty, since (once again) inlining becomes impossible for the compiler.

For a further discussion of the last two options, also see [**this Q&A on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435549/when-to-use-stdfunction-instead-of-inheritance/16436690#16436690).

Comment: could you explain the `=` in the lambda? i'm still rubbing my eyes though:-)

Comment: @Koushik: It captures the `fortyTwo` variable by value. A non-capturing lambda would not have been a good examples, since those can be implicitly converted to function pointers ;)

Comment: the [=] makes it default to capturing value by value (rather than reference). SO it captures the value 42 for fortyTwo rather than a reference to it. Which means if you assigned 111 to it afterwards the lambda would still use the value 42 it captured.

Comment: @Koushik: You mean, as a way of capturing? No, not in C++11. If you mean as the lambda's parameter (`[] (int const&) { ... }`), yes, you can, but for `int` I would not bother accepting by reference to `const`

Comment: @AndyProwl i did mean capturing. now learnt thanks:-) and thanks to jcoder too:-)

Comment: Using `template<typename F> void doParam(int i, F f)` doesn't tell teh

Answer (score 5):

**Template parameters**

1. have to be known at **compile time**.
2. lead to one function instantation for every distinct value of the parameter (so-called **template bloat**)
3. the called function is transparant to the compiler (**inlining**, but could lead to even more bloat, double-edged sword)
4. the calling function can be **overloaded** for particular values of the parameter, without modifying **existing code**

**Function pointers**

1. are passed at **run time**.
2. only lead to one calling function (**smaller object code**)
3. the called function is typically opaque to the compiler (**no inlining**)
4. the calling function needs a runtime `if`/`switch` to do special stuff for special values of the parameter, this is **brittle**

When to use which version: if you need speed and a lot of customization, use templates. If you need flexibility at runtime, but not in the implementation, use function pointers.

As @AndyProwl points out: if you have a C++11 compiler, function pointers are generalized to callable objects such as `std::function` and lambda expressions. This opens up a whole new can of worms (in a good sense).