# When to pass a parameter as template argument rather than function argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand when it is required or recommended to design a function template to receive one or more parameters as template argument instead of ordinary function arguments. For instance, in the implementation of StaticVector in the Blaze library under `blaze/math/dense/StaticVector.h`, the homogeneous constructor receives the parameter `N` corresponding to the size of the vector as a template argument:

```
inline StaticVector<Type,N,TF,AF,PF,Tag>::StaticVector( const Type& init )
   // v_ is intentionally left uninitialized
{
   using blaze::clear;

   for( size_t i=0UL; i<N; ++i )
      v_[i] = init;

   for( size_t i=N; i<NN; ++i )
      clear( v_[i] );

   BLAZE_INTERNAL_ASSERT( isIntact(), "Invariant violation detected" );
}
```

I have seen for instance in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440029/c-function-passed-as-template-argument-vs-parameter) that performance has been mentioned as a reason for such design. However, it seems to be possible to pass the size parameter to the constructor as a regular function argument and still benefit from function inlining in this case. Is that right? Or is it the overloading possibility that is the main design idea here? In any case, what are the various implications of each variant?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if something is a compile-time constant it should be a template parameter, if something is not a compile-time constant it cannot be a template parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I believe that with `consteval` (and even before that, to an extent, with `constexpr`) this general rule no longer holds.

Comment: Feel free, @KonradRudolph, to offer an example of a template that compiles with one of its parameters specified at runtime.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That obviously wouldn’t work, and I believe you know that this isn’t what I mean. — Obviously (?!) I meant that compile-time constants no longer have to be template parameters to still allow compile-time evaluation of the function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph 's point of view is really the essence of my question. It's an interesting discussion though; thanks for your inputs Sam and Konrad

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking about function templates (as worded in the question text) or class templates (as shown in the code example)? There's a difference...

Comment: Actually I was not aware of the implied differences for the class and function templates. It would be very nice to go through both cases